# c#: Using enter for KeyDown does not work

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am playing with a basic calculator windows app and trying to make it calculate the equation when pressing the enter key. Currently, if I give it 2+2 and click my equal button it registers 4, as it should.  I would like to get the same response when I hit the enter key on the keyboard. I am attempting to do this with this code:

```cs
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    equal.PerformClick();
}
```

the result is 2+22(last number entered is duplicated)
However, if I use a letter or F-key(as in the below code) it returns the correct answer:

```cs
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C) 
{
    equal.PerformClick();
}
```

For reference the following is the code that "equal.PerformClick()" is calling

```cs
decimal numA;
decimal numB;
decimal result = 0;
//-------------------------------------------------------------
decimal.TryParse(this.first_num_label.Text, out numA);
decimal.TryParse(this.label1.Text, out numB);
if (this.operator_name.Text == "+")
{
    result = numA + numB;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
if (this.operator_name.Text == "-")
{
    result = numA - numB;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
if (this.operator_name.Text == "x")
{
    result = numA * numB;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
if (this.operator_name.Text == "/")
{
    result = numA / numB;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
this.label1.Text = result.ToString();
this.first_num_label.Text = "";
this.operator_name.Text = "";
```

here is the entire code:.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calc_project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.label1.Text = "";
            this.label1.ResetText();
        }

        private void one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "1";
        }

        private void two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "2";
        }

        private void three_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "3";
        }

        private void four_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "4";
        }

        private void five_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "5";
        }

        private void six_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "6";
        }

        private void seven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "7";
        }

        private void eight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "8";
        }

        private void nine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "9";
        }

        private void zero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "0";
        }

        private void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operator_name.Text = "+";
            if (this.label1.Text != "")
            {
                this.first_num_label.Text = this.label1.Text;
            }
            this.label1.ResetText();
        }

        private void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operator_name.Text = "-";
            if (this.label1.Text != "")
            {
                this.first_num_label.Text = this.label1.Text;
            }
            this.label1.ResetText();
        }

        private void multiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operator_name.Text = "x";
            if (this.label1.Text != "")
            {
                this.first_num_label.Text = this.label1.Text;
            }
            this.label1.ResetText();
        }

        private void div_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operator_name.Text = "/";
            if (this.label1.Text != "")
            {
                this.first_num_label.Text = this.label1.Text;
            }
            this.label1.ResetText();
        }
        

        private void equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal numA;
            decimal numB;
            decimal result = 0;
            //-------------------------------------------------------------
            decimal.TryParse(this.first_num_label.Text, out numA);
            decimal.TryParse(this.label1.Text, out numB);
            if (this.operator_name.Text == "+")
            {
                result = numA + numB;
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            if (this.operator_name.Text == "-")
            {
                result = numA - numB;
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            if (this.operator_name.Text == "x")
            {
                result = numA * numB;
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            if (this.operator_name.Text == "/")
            {
                result = numA / numB;
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            this.label1.Text = result.ToString();
            this.first_num_label.Text = "";
            this.operator_name.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.ResetText();
            this.first_num_label.ResetText();
            this.operator_name.ResetText();
        }

        private void Decimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + ".";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal len;
            decimal wit;
            decimal area;
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox1.Text, out len);
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox2.Text, out wit);
            area = len * wit;
            if (ft.Checked == true)
            {
                this.label2.Text = area.ToString() +" square feet";
            }
            if (meters.Checked == true)
            {
                this.label2.Text = area.ToString() +" square meters";
            }
            if (cm.Checked == true)
            {
                this.label2.Text = area.ToString() + " square centimeters";
            }
            if (yards.Checked == true)
            {
                this.label2.Text = area.ToString() + " square yards";
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    this.label2.Text = area.ToString();
            //}

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            this.textBox2.Text = "";
            this.label2.ResetText();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal ar;
            decimal cov;
            decimal req;
            //--------------------------------------------
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox4.Text, out ar);
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox3.Text, out cov);
            //--------------------------------------------
            req = ar / cov;
            this.requirement.Text = req.ToString() + " Gallons";
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal Slabar;
            decimal Slabtk;
            decimal TKft;
            decimal cubFt;
            decimal ConYard;
            //--------------------------------------------
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox5.Text, out Slabar);
            decimal.TryParse(this.textBox6.Text, out Slabtk);
            //--------------------------------------------
            TKft = Slabtk / 12;
            cubFt = Slabar * TKft;
            ConYard = cubFt / 27;
            //--------------------------------------------
            this.label10.Text = ConYard.ToString();

        }

             
        private void tabControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                equal.PerformClick();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) //this code works
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) //so does this
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad9) // also works
            {
                this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "9";
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) 
            {
                equal.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "However, it will not work with the enter key, just the enter key." Huh?

Comment: This is lacking a lot of information, not least of which what technology. Please add the relevant tags and show us a [mcve]

Comment: Any other key I select(letters, F-keys) will work just fine, just not enter.

Comment: Your question is really unclear but, for a start, `Keys.Enter` and `Keys.Return` are exactly the same thing, as per the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) so what two keys are you actually trying to use?

Comment: I used both while searching for the issue as I mentioned I am very new to C#

Comment: The issue is not your newness to C#, it's that your question, especially this sentence, makes no sense: "complete the equation when pressing enter the same as it would when clicking the enter button. However, it will not work with the enter key, just the enter key." - Please clarify your question.

Comment: The question could be more clear, please try to rewrite. That being said, i think the problem is elsewhere in your code , please post the rest.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite and I have added the entire code at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, your code works well. If you still have problems, I suggest you can use Form_KeyDown event.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                equal.PerformClick();
            }
         }
```

I fixed the control focus to textbox1 to prevent the Enter key from being affected by the input number.

After each number is entered, please set textBox1.Focus(). method.

As shown below:

```
 private void one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "1";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + "2";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        ......
        ......
```

Finally, it is best for you to check if the enter key is normal.

Comment: Thanks, I actually stumbled across this same solution late last night and hadn't had a chance to update this question yet.  I'm glad to see it is a reasonable solution, not a funky band-aid

Comment: I modified the code and the enter key now functions as I want it to.  Somehow the code just feels clunky and bloated.  I'm going to keep learning and revisit as I go.

Comment: @TravisRichards, I am glad that your question has been solved, you can you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are listening on the `KeyPress` event? If so, have you tried casting the `Keys.Enter` value to a char?

```
private void element_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

`Keys.Enter` and `Keys.Return` return the same value, so it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Comment: What else would need to be added? This gives the following error: CS1061 'KeyEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyChar' and no accessible extension method 'KeyChar' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I see you are using the `KeyDown` event. The only thing I can think of is that the KeyDown event of the Enter-Key is swallowed by your button. I suggest changing the KeyDown event to a `KeyUp` event. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I got the same result as with the KeyDown event.  There must be some other issue in my code, I'll just have to go through line by line.  Thank you for your suggestions